# Invariants of the symmetric group

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory

Let $V_\lambda$ be an irreducible representation  of the symmetric group $S_n$ as usual labeled by parition $\lambda$ of $n.$

**Question.** 
Is there any general information about   the algebra of invariants $\mathbb{C}[V_\lambda]^{S_n}$: minimal generating set,  number of generators, constructive algorithms, usefull isomorphisms?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb C[V_\lambda]$?

Comment: It is the algebra of polynomial  functions on the complex vector space $V_\lambda.$

Comment: The algebra of polynomial functions on $V$ as a representation of $G$ is given by $\bigoplus_{n\ge0}U^{\otimes n}$, where $U$ is the dual representation of $V$. I presume $(U^{\otimes n})^G$ is going to be nontrivial for an infinite number number of $n$s. One can compute the dimension of $(U^{\otimes n})^G$ by computing the matrix of the linear map $-\mapsto -\otimes U$ on the representation ring ${\rm Rep}(G)$, which is itself an array of structure constants, and then taking it to the $n$th power and locating the $U$th/$\Bbb C$th row/column. For $G=S_n$, we speak of Littlewood-Richardson.